Is it safe to keep the firebaseConfig object in the Vue3 client
I am following the instruction in Add Firebase to your JavaScript project (link) which suggests the following code:
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'; 
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'; 

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ENV_APIKEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ENV_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ENV_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ENV_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ENV_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ENV_APPID,
};

// Initialize app with firebasseConfig
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firestore
const db = getFirestore(app);

// Initialize Firebase Auth
const auth = getAuth(app);

// Export the initialized instances
export { app, db, auth };

My question is that the apiKey, authDomain, etc. are all availabe in the source of my Vue3 SPA, which seems like a security hole. Is this safe or is there some other level of security I need to be implementing?
